# What is the seed of this Minecraft image?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If you play Minecraft, there is an excellent chance that you've seen this picture before:

[image]

This image is shown at the minecraft.net website. Just recently, I've been starting to wonder: is there a seed for this picture? All of the terrain in this image looks very natural. The trees in this image also have different patterns, so it is very likely that this is a real Minecraft seed, and Mojang just made this Minecraft seed into an art. I'm very curious - is there a seed for this world, or is there a world for this picture so that we can recreate the picture or play on this world?

Comment: It's very unlikely that anyone here happens to know the seed of this image. However, the seeds to other images have been found, most notably [pack.png](http://packpng.com/method/). You can have a look at how they did it and try it yourself here.

Comment: The village is not naturally generated, just crafted from assets by a 3D artist. See the right-most house. It's two vanilla houses merged into one in violation of natural generation rules. Similarly the house with fenced area has another 'cube' house glued to its back. Additionally, there are no roads whatsoever. Blue Orchids only generate in swamp, lilacs only generate in forests, and the cloud pattern is absent in the [cloud map](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/File:Environment01.png). In short, a fake artistic vision. The only probable natural generation is the far background mountain.

Comment: I am voting to close this question since this will be answered with opinions to the image rather than the real seed.

Comment: I vote to not close this question. A valid answer is still possible stating that this image is made by hand instead of using a real world from a specific seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. As explained by SF in the comments, it was an artistic vision.
You can try to recreate it yourself, but it wouldn't be the same.